# in array length to get form input textfield

Tags: javascript

I am writing a short arrays loop and event handler program here i want to to enter array length through input text field if i write 10 array length become 10 and window prompt 10 times if i write 2 array length become 2 here i my code please check it this is not working

```
<html>
<TITLE>Javascript Arrays</TITLE>
<BODY bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
    <h1>Implementation of Sort and Reverse Functions </h>
    <h2>Enter number of Elements</h2>
    <form name="Anonymous Ghost">
        <INPUT type="number" name="takeinput" id="valueField" size="30">
        <Input type="button" name="name1" value="Take Input" onClick="a()">
    </form>
    <form name="Anonymous Ghost">
        <Input type="button" name="name2" value="Ascending" onClick="b()">
        <Input type="button" name="name3" value="Descending" onClick="c()">
    </form>

</BODY>
<SCRIPT>

    words = new Array(4);

    function a() {
        for (k = 0; k < words.length; k = k + 1) {
            words[k] = window.prompt("Enter word # " + k, "");

        }
    }

    function b() {
        words.sort();
        document.write("SORTED WORDS:" + "<BR>");
        for (k = 0; k < words.length; k = k + 1) {
            document.write(words[k] + "<BR>");
        }
    }

    function c() {
        words.sort();
        words.reverse();
        document.write("SORTED WORDS:" + "<BR>");
        for (k = 0; k < words.length; k = k + 1) {
            document.write(words[k] + "<BR>");
        }
    }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Please check my codes and tell me where i wrong....

Comment: I don't know js yet, but there are many problems with your HTML. You don't close the h1 element properly. You have two body elements. You're closing a head element that you never opened.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function a() to this

```
function a() {
    var val = parseInt(document.getElementById('valueField').value)
    var words = new Array(val);
    for (k = 0; k < words.length; k = k + 1) {
        words[k] = window.prompt("Enter word # " + k, "");
    }
}
```

**Mistakes and Solution**

**Mistake**

```
words = new Array(4);
```

**4** is hardcoded. It will always take 4 whatever you enter in input field

**Solution**

get value from the input field, convert it to integer and then create array using that value

**Why parseInt()?**

```
new Array("5")
["5"]
```

It will make an array with single element having value 5

```
new Array(5)
[undefined × 5]
```

It will make an array of length 5 with undefined values

Comment: Is your problem resolved, If yes then please accept it else add a comment.